# SSD has large amount of total writes

Tags: windows-7, ssd

The drive is a Kingston HyperX 120GB (the one with blue trim not the black 3k model) and it's been used as an OS drive and for some programs, mostly intensive/large ones, but also Chrome and a few other common use ones. It is also used as a scratch disk for Photoshop and other design programs, although I do not use them heavily enough to cause this ridiculous amount of writes. For a long time I had pagefile disabled too, then only several months ago I made a 1GB pagefile on it, then upped to a 2GB one for a while but it has since been dropped to 1GB again.
I've had since about march last year and it's mostly shutdown every night, it's left on if I'm out for the night though and this makes the power on count puzzling for me too.

Hopefully this explains the use situation well enough, now this is what I saw (screenshot from CrystalDisk Info)

[image: Screenshot]

Why is the total writes value so high, given its usage?

Comment: Did you use TweakSSD to optimize your OS settings? Have you changed your browser settings to cache in memory instead of hdd? What are your normal activities? Have you disabled hibernation?

Comment: I have not used TweakSSD. It caches wherever Chrome does by default, I assume that is on the SSD? Not much of what I use regularly is installed on the SSD, Chrome and a few other commonly used programs, Photoshop and other design programs are installed on there but only in the past 6-8 months and they haven't been used heavily. Yes hibernation has always been disabled, hybrid-sleep wasn't but it's only been in sleep mode less than ~20 times.

Comment: How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: 8GB. It's not enough anymore. That is why I activated pagefile.

Answer (score 4):

If you got the SSD in March of last year that means you've had it for about 16 months or ~500 days. 4.31 * 1000 / 500 amounts to around 8-9 GB per day. That is not a big amount at all, and less than I was expecting given your described usage. 10GB per day is a common number thrown around for how many writes the average user (that doesn't do anything special like Photoshop) produces.

Where do these writes come from? Lots of small stuff that adds up. Cache file writes, temp file writes, log file writes, session file writes, page file writes, updates. All produced by all the stuff running on your computer.

As an example I was curious about the writes produced by Firefox, so I logged all writes for a 24 hour period. In order to be able to recover the session after a crash Firefox writes it to disk a few times a minute. I have a large session (100+ tabs) so each time Firefox saved it it wrote ~1.5MB to disk. Leave it running 24h a day and it adds up to a few GB on its own.

You are doing a little above 3TB per year. At that rate you probably have a 100+ years of usable write lifespan left in your SSD. Or, put differently, something else in the SSD will probably fail before you wear it out.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome caches a lot.

If your OS settings allow the drive to be powered down after so many minutes  it may be doing this and that could account for your power on/off count - it would be doing this even if the system doesn't go into any sleep mode.

[image]

I could be wrong but I believe any video played via Flash is written to some sort of cache before being rendered.  So if you've been watching a lot of online videos it could be the cause.  This is also a possibility if you use an online streaming service such as Pandora or Spotify.

You may need to use some sort of disk usage monitoring tool to be sure if you have absolutely no idea.

Comment: My drives are set to never sleep. It is probably Chrome cache then as I do watch a lot of youtube/streams. Is there any point in changing the cache location or is it not worth it?

Comment: If you're worried about writes and have a spinning HD handy and installed I'd say look into moving it.

Comment: I doubt his internet connection is fast enough to be able to download enough data for the caching to amount to a significant amount of writes.

Comment: I guess it depends how it's done, I have 130Mb/s down but data capped at 100GB. So come to think of it... I'm not sure